# Angular - cdkDrag is not working with span tag

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-cdk, angular-cdk-drag-drop

I am using Angular Material's [Drag and Drop Module](https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/overview). How ever `cdkDrag` doesn't seem to work with `span` and other few tags that I observed like `a` tag.

**component.html**

```html
<div class='user' *ngFor='let user of usersTask; let i = index'>
  User:  {{i}}
  <span class='task' *ngFor='let task of user' cdkDropList cdkDrag>
    {{task}}
  </span>
</div>
```

**component.ts**

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'some-root',
  templateUrl: './some.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./some.component.scss']
})
export class SomeComponent {
  usersTask = [[
    'Get to work',
    'Pick up groceries',
    'Go home',
    'Fall asleep'
  ],[
    'Get up',
    'Brush teeth',
    'Take a shower',
    'Check e-mail',
    'Walk dog'
  ]];
}
```

But, It works, if I replace `span` with `div` tag.

Any idea, why is this happening? And how to solve this issue?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you need a cdkDragList and differents cdkDrag inside the cdkDragList -can not be the same tag-

Comment: I didn't understand, could you explain more, with few examples?

Comment: you has in `<span cdkDropList cdkDrag>`, I supose you want `<div *ngFor=".." cdkDropList><span *ngFor=".." cdkDrag>` (I put in the way of answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See that the `cdkDropList`is in the "div", not in the "span"

```
<div class='user' *ngFor='let user of usersTask; let i = index' cdkDropList >
  User:  {{i}}
  <span class='task' *ngFor='let task of user' cdkDrag>
    {{task}}
  </span>
</div>
```